# TypeORM - JSONB where object in array LIKE value

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, typeorm

I'm trying to port this query to TypeORM, and I cannot figure it out. Does anyone have any suggestions? I keep receiving column not found errors

```
SELECT id FROM study, jsonb_array_elements(findings) as elem WHERE elem->>'id'='patientName' AND  elem->>'value' ILIKE '%Dom%';
```

Here is my TypeORM query:

```
createQueryBuilder()
      .select(['id'])
      .addSelect('jsonb_array_elements(findings)', 'elem')
      .from(DbStudy, 'study')
      .andWhere(`"elem"->>"id" = 'patientName'`)
      .andWhere(`"elem"->>"value" ILIKE :patientName`, {
        patientName: `%${name}%`,
      });
```

It ends up generating a query like:

```
SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements(findings) AS "elem" FROM "study" "study" WHERE "elem"->>"id" = 'patientName' AND "elem"->>"value" ILIKE $1
```

Which doesn't work column "elem" does not exist.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question. Is there something about it which is not satisfactory?

Comment: What exactly is the output you want? Each element from the array as a separate row? Or just rows from the table when at least one element in the array contains the name?

Comment: I've repurposed the question. I asked prematurely sorry

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Yeah, I moved off TypeORM. Sorry I can't be of more help